# Export drawing from solid to 3d pdf

Tags: pdf, 3d, solidworks

We are creating a presentation of engineering drawings created in solidworks. We want these files to be exported as 3D Pdf. The drawings have different layers. How to export these layers as layers and toggle views as required.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SolidWorks itself doesn't provide such capabilities and I'm not aware of other tools that can do this. The only way I see is to write your own app that separate a drawing by layers and export into 3D PDF. Libraries like [HOOPS Publish](http://www.techsoft3d.com/our-products/hoops-publish) may come in handy.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion. Does AutoCad provide this support? In that case we can try export to DWG from solidworks and from Autocad export to PDF preserving layers

Comment: I don't know for sure about AutoCAD. IMHO I think it doesn't.
Try out [3D PDF for AutoCAD](http://www.tetra4d.com/products/plugins/3d-pdf-for-autocad).
I think it should be a pretty simple functionality for them to implement.